# database schema question

Tags: database, database-design, schema

I need some suggestions in the database design schema I've created below... I am not sure that it's correct.. in terms of relationship. Especially the USER - USER_RESERVATION - RESERVATION.
What I am trying to say is that a USER can have many RESERVATION, but then the same RESERVATION can belong to many different USERS... am I representing it correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user can have many reservations and each reservation can be for many users, you are correct to have a USER_RESERVATION table to do the many-to-many mapping.

Off the top of my head, though, it seems odd that a reservation would belong to multiple users.  I would tend to think that each user would have a separate reservation in the system and that there would be some concept of linked reservations.  So if a family of four wants to take a flight, Mom, Dad, and each kid would have a separate reservation with a separate ticket but all four reservations would be linked together in the system for certain operations like checking in.  Separate reservations, though, would tend to simplify rebooking tasks if, say, Mom needed to move her flight back a day or if the family needed to be rebooked on two separate flights because their flight was cancelled.

Comment: Yes, a reservation can belong to multiple users.

I was just thinking what would happen if a user cancels a reservation in my case... 

What needs to be changed if I want to have a separate reservation? Remove that USER_RESERVATION table and just directly connect USER to RESERVATIONS?

Comment: If you wanted each user to have a separate reservation, you could remove the USER_RESERVATION table and add a RESERVATION_OWNER column to the RESERVATION table that was a foreign key back to the USER table.  To model a group of related reservations, the simplest option is likely to add a self-referential MASTER_RESERVATION_ID column to the RESERVATION table.

Comment: so the UID would be the foreign key in the RESERVATION table to know the owner of the RESERVATION? can the combination of RID, DID, and RESID be a self-referential? so I don't need the MASTER_RESERVATION_ID

Comment: You need the MASTER_RESERVATION_ID if you want the ability to tie together multiple individual reservation records.  The MASTER_RESERVATION_ID column in the RESERVATION table would be a foreign key to the RESERVATION_ID in the RESERVATION table so the foreign key would be self-referential in that it referred back to the primary key of the same table.  If you just want to have each individual have their own reservation, you'd want a RESERVATION_USER_ID column in the RESERVATION table that was a foreign key to the USER_ID column in the USER table.

Comment: If that is the case, then in a tuple we'll have 2 columns with two RID values, one which is the PK and one is the FK?

Comment: If RID is a form of RESERVATION_ID, then yes.  You'd have a primary key column (RESERVATION_ID) and a foreign key column (MASTER_RESERVATION_ID) that referenced the RESERVATION_ID of a different row in the same RESERVATION table.  If you'd prefer, you could also model that with a separate MASTER_RESERVATION table and a 1-to-many mapping table between MASTER_RESERVATION and RESERVATION.  That would make more sense if there were attributes of a master reservation that were not attributes of an individual reservation but I can't think of any need for that.